# Replacing values in dataset within Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure Machine Learning studio I need to convert a column of data that has three categorical values 'yes', 'no' and 'maybe', and wish to combine the 'no' and 'maybe' values as just 'no'.

I can do this easily using SQL, R, or Python but for these purposes I need to show if it is possible to do this without using these languages. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm fine if the answer is no but I don't want to say it's not possible if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done! :)

You would just use the "Group Categorical Values" module. Choose the column that has the data you want to group, and you can set the values like the following:

[image]

What's going on here is that the default, which will get used if the other levels aren't caught, is set to "yes". Then when any values are "no", or "maybe", it gets grouped into a category of "no".

However, this will error unless you make that column a categorical type, so you would need to use the "Edit Metadata" module to do that.

[image]

The example I used is [published to the gallery](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Replace-Values-in-Dataset), if you need to reference it.

If you need more info, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that

Comment: @Danrex Glad it helped!